# Require Formtastic styles in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, require, sass

Formtastic help says to add next lines in application.css:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
*= require formtastic
*= require my_formtastic_changes
```

But what i'm gonna do when it is scss? Can't find it in search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theres nothing left to do for you, place your my_formtastic_changes.scss in app/assets/stylesheets. Rails will automagically compile your scss file and add it to application.css

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that styles could be more beautiful:)